# Multiple Switch.setTextOn() not updating switch's text

Tags: android, uiswitch

I have two `Switch`s buttons in my android Activity.
Both have custom dynamic On/Off texts (that are set at runtime with `Switch.setTextOn(CharSeq)` ).
They look like this (image found on another SO thread):
 [image: custom switch text]
The first switch's on/off texts are set once.

**My goal is to dynamically modify the on/off texts of the second switch, when the state of the first switch changed.**

So I set up a `OnCheckedChangeListener` on the first switch like this:

```
 switch2.setTextOff("ImOff");  // works, the text is updated on the switch

 switch2.setTextOn("ImOn"); // same here

 switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(!isChecked)
                {
                   switch2.setTextOff(myStrings.get(2));  
                   switch2.setTextOn(myStrings.get(3));  // here switch2.getTextOn() returns the value of myStrings.get(3), but the widget still displays ImOn...
                } else
                {
                   switch2.setTextOff(myStrings.get(4));  
                   switch2.setTextOn(myStrings.get(5)); // here switch2.getTextOn() returns the value of myStrings.get(5), but the widget still displays ImOn...
                }
                // I tried to update the switch with this and this
                switch2.invalidate();
                switch2.setChecked(valuesSwitch.isChecked());
            }
        });
```

**But this code doesn't work, the on/off texts of the second switch are set on the object (`getTextOn/Off` returns the right text), but widget still displays the initial text ImOn/ImOff ...**

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in this link,

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/1IYypcoYXlk

In a derived class (Which extends switch),  override the Following method:

```
Override
public void request layout () {
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field mOnLayout = Switch.class.getDeclaredField ( "mOnLayout");
        mOnLayout.setAccessible (true);
        mOnLayout.set (this, null);
        java.lang.reflect.Field mOffLayout = Switch.class.getDeclaredField ( "mOffLayout");
        mOffLayout.setAccessible (true) ;
        mOffLayout.set (this, null);
    } Catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e (TAG, ex.getMessage (), ex);
    }
    super.requestLayout ();
}
```